# Converting a json schema to angular-tree-control treemodel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jsonschema

I have a very large [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) which I would like to display in an [Angular Tree Control](https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control). However, the json schema is not exactly in the treemodel format supported by the Angular Tree Control. For example, the children (properties) in the schema are not in an array. How would I go about converting the json schema into a treemodel format?

The schema looks something like this (except more complicated with up to 10 levels of nesting):

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "object",
             "properties": {
                 "addressLine1": {
                      "type": "string"
                  },
                  "addressLine2": {
                       "type": "string"
                  }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

For it to render correctly in the Angular Tree Control, it needs to look like this:

```
{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "firstName",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "lastName",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "address",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": [
                      {
                          "name": "addressLine1",
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      {
                           "name": "addressLine2",
                           "type": "string"
                      }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your current schema?

Comment: Edited with schema example

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, can be refactored to be recursive to deeper levels.

```js
var data = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "object",
             "properties": {
                 "addressLine1": {
                      "type": "string"
                  },
                  "addressLine2": {
                       "type": "string"
                  }
             }
         }
     }
};

function toTreeModel(obj){
 var treeModel = {};

 for (var a in obj) {
  if(a === 'properties'){
   treeModel[a] = []
   var i = 0;
   var e = 0;
   for(b in obj[a]){
    if(obj[a][b].type === 'object'){
     treeModel[a][i] = {name: b, type: obj[a][b].type, properties: []};
     for(c in obj[a][b].properties){
      treeModel[a][i].properties.push({name: c, type: obj[a][b].properties[c].type});
      e++;
     }
    } else {
     treeModel[a][i] = {name: b, type: obj[a][b].type};
    }
    i++;
   }
  } else {
   treeModel[a] = obj[a];
  }
 }
 return treeModel;
}

var toTree = toTreeModel(data);
// console.log(toTree);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(toTree, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

it support nested also

```
var data = {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "checked": {
          "type": "boolean",
        },
        "dimensions": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "width": {
              "type": "integer",
            },
            "height": {
              "type": "integer",
            },
            "volume": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "length": {
                  "type":"integer",
                },
                "breadth":{
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "number",
        }
      }
    }


function findProperties(obj){
  let properties = []
  for(key in obj){
    if(obj[key].properties){
      properties.push({name: key, datatype: obj[key].type, properties: findProperties(obj[key].properties)})
    }else{
      properties.push({ name: key, datatype: obj[key].type});
    }
  }
  return properties;
}

function findData(data){
  let result = "";
  for(key in data){
    if(key == 'properties'){
      result = findProperties(data.properties)
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(findData(data)));
```